# inserting a certain text between in every occurrence of two following tabs

Tags: linux, text, sed

I am trying to insert NA between every occurrence of two tab characters immediately following each other in a text file. How can I do it with a sed command?

Comment: Try google. StackOverflow is a site for specific questions about problems with things you've tried. A generic how-to question without any research done (and plenty of resources on google) is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry I didn't state this but I actually tried to find it on the web but couldn't find anything that helped me. And also I am a newbie so I couldn't make something out of similar questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which can easily be solved by the most basic introduction or documentation on sed.

Comment: @torazaburo actually the question appears easy but is deceptive because the obvious pattern for substitution precludes adjacent patterns and FWIW I think this question is quite well stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\t\t/\tNA\t/g;ta' file
```

This covers all occurrances of `\t\t` throughout a file

Or if you prefer:

```
sed 's/\t\t/\tNA\t/g;s//\tNA\t/g' file
```

Comment: thanks so much it worked just fine. could you please explain the functions :, a, ;, and ta?

Comment: @EmrahAydin `:a` is a goto point called `a` and `ta` means if the last substitution occured then jump to the goto point `a`. If the first substitution is true and the program jumps back to `a`. The second substitution may or may not be true, if it is it jumps back again to `a` if it is not the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sed 's/xx/xNAx/g' file
```

where you type `x` using `Control-V TAB`

Or, if you have GNU sed, you can type:

```
sed 's/\t\t/\tNA\t/g' file
```

Comment: I used this one already but the problem is this doesn't cover all the occurrences of tabs following immediately each other, for example in the case of 3 or more tabs following each other. Thanks much for your answer btw.